# How to change date format and position in find output

Tags: scripting, find

Say i have the following command. It's set to display a list of the last 20 files modified on my drive with the paths included.

```
find -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort -r | head -20
```

The command works fine however in the format of the date and time there is too much information as it also displays the milliseconds. My questions were how would I remove this. In addition, how could I change the position it prints in so that the path would show up on the left side and the date on the right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

```
find -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %.8TT %p\n' | sort -r | sed -r 's/(^[^ ]+ [^ ]+) (.+)/\2 \1/' | head -20
```

Putting `.8` between `%` and `TT` modifies that field to limit it to 8 characters (`hh:mm:ss`).  The `sed` regex moves the first part of the line (to sets of non-space characters with one space between) to the end of the line.  It's necessary for the time to be at the beginning of the line for the `sort` command.

**Warning:** Putting the date after the file name could potentially cause confusion if filenames are displayed that contain spaces and numbers.  However, for viewing as a human rather that for feeding into another script or program, this output should be fine.

Otherwise, to leave the times in front of the filenames:

```
find -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %.8TT %p\n' | sort -r | head -20
```

**EDIT:** `sed` is unnecessary for trimming fractional second per @steeldriver's comment.  This may be a GNU extension, but `-printf` doesn't appear to be POSIX anyway.  Also, corrected sorting bug.

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for your help. The layout is as i wanted however putting the text before the date seems to cause issues so i think i may leave that part out. However, when i keep the command as in my original while ONLY adding the sed regex it doesn't seem to remove the additional numerals (milliseconds). Why could this be ?

Comment: At least with the GNU version of `find`, you can specify a *precision* for the time field e.g. to print exactly 8 characters `hh:mm:ss` (omitting the fractional seconds), replace `%TT` by `%.8TT`

Comment: @flowoftruth Fixed.